# Pop up Views in ios

Tags: ios, popup

I have a location  button. I want to open a pop up view when location button got pressed. like this

[image]

when this view opened, all buttons and background view should be blurred.
How can i achieve this??
thnx for any kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

To show the view with alert like animation create a popView you want to show and follow the below code:

```
popView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
[self.view addSubview:popView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
    popView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
        popView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
           popView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        }];
    }];
}];

popView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Hide the other views visible.

Comment: I'll use your trick but what is popView in your example? Is it UIView?

Comment: Thanx. Did you get your solution?

Comment: No, not yet. i'll search

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the below code

```
  -(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
   {
     popView.hidden = NO;
     //OR
     [self.view addSubview:popView];
     btn1.hidden = YES;
     btn2.hidden = YES;
     btn3.hidden = YES;
     view1.hidden = YES;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

Create one view & size of that view will be size of parent view. Your second view will contain your UI along with black blur view at background.

When you tap on the location button display that view so all other button will be hidden automatically.

Comment: Add blur view as background images on second view which you are going to display when user click on the location button. Let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Comment: if i'll make view and displayed it when button pressed then it will just open but the dialogue box will not appear. it means if you take a look at the image, the view is notifying the button. how can i achieve this

Comment: Add that button to other view as well, If you don't have any issue in that. Let me know if you have issue in that..

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get you. Can u help me with some codes to i can understand.

Comment: Let me clarify... I just wanted to say on second vie add the Cross button which is there in parent view. So what happen when you click on that button second view which you are adding will have same button. Got it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78998/discussion-between-m-swapnil-and-nilesh-patel).